# Vue - Importing external JSON without reloading

Tags: json, vue.js

I am running into an issue with reactive data being reset each time a JSON file is updated.

The JSON file is a database of previous messages that is to be loaded initially once, in the created() cycle:

```
created() {
     const database = require('../../db.json');
     this.messages = database.messages
},
```

On the server side, any new messages will update this JSON file. However when this happens, it triggers a new import in the Vue application and the data values are reset.

I would like to only import this data once, on load - is there a way?

Comment: Are you saying your component is being reloaded automatically as soon as the `db.json` file is updated? Are you sure this isn't just happening when running the development server which watches imported modules for changes and reloads them (aka hot reloading)?

Comment: Ahh that could be it.. I'll deploy and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a deep copy of database.messages.

```
created(){
    ...
    this.messages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(database.messages));
```

Comment: No problem. Just bear in mind that most of the time you don't want to do this! You're duplicating information and creating a syncing problem.